# Unit test RxJava code

Tags: java, mockito, rx-java2

I'm using `Retrofit` together with `RxJava` to fetch some data from the network, map it to viewmodel objects and call view to display the data.

This is how my code looks :

```
@Override
public void onLoadData() {
view.showProgressBar();

service.fetchCVRF(createRequestBody())
        .map(this::mapToViewModels)
        .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
        .observeOn(schedulerProvider.mainThread())
        .subscribe(viewModels -> {
            if (view != null) {
                view.hideProgressBar();
                view.showData(viewModels);
            }
        }, throwable -> {
            if (view != null) {
                view.hideProgressBar();
            }
            Timber.i(throwable, "onLoadData ");
        });
}
```

I want to unit test the above code with `Mockito` so what I did is :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CvrfPresenterTest {

@Mock private CvrfMVP.View view;
@Mock private CvrfService service;
@Mock private SharedPreferencesManager prefManager;

private BaseSchedulerProvider schedulerProvider;

private CvrfPresenter presenter;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    schedulerProvider = new ImmediateSchedulerProvider();

    presenter = new CvrfPresenter(view, service, prefManager, schedulerProvider);
}

@Test
public void onLoadData() throws Exception {
    // Given
    when(service.fetchCVRF(any(RequestBody.class)))
        .thenReturn(Single.just(response()));
    when(service.fetchCVRF(any(RequestBody.class)).map(any()))
            .thenReturn(Single.just(viewModels()));

    // When
    presenter.onLoadData();

    // Then
    verify(view).showData(anyList());
}

private Response<CvrfResponse> response() {
    return Response.success(new CvrfResponse());
}

private List<CvrfViewModel> viewModels() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

}
```

The problem with the above code is that when I run it throws `NullPointerException` for the second `when`. Isn't this how am I supposed to unit test this code? I think my code is fine but I don't understand why it gives `NPE` when `map` operator is called, since I already have defined in the first `when` what it should return.

Comment: What is the `.map(any())` doing in your `when` statement? That is not a proper way to mock a return value.

Comment: But then how should I mock it?

Comment: Your first `when` statement is where your inject a value into the observer chain. You would then mock `this::mapToViewModels` so that the value you inject is mapped properly, if that is what you need to do.